# Creating a transparent loading overlay

Tags: html, css

Using the same markup *(shown below)*, is it possible to add a style which creates a transparent background overlay i.e. a loading overlay? When I try to add a background to `.loading` CSS it only adds it to the background of the `.loading` element and not the body. The style `.loading` gets removed (via jQuery) so ideally I want the overlay to be somehow be connected to `.loading`, if possible?

**HTML**

```
<div class=loading style-2>
    content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1px;

  margin: 5em;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  }

.style-1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #444 transparent;
  }

.style-2 {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #ccc transparent;
  }

.style-3 {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #444 #fff #fff;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); }
  }

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); }
  }

@-o-keyframes spin {
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); }
  }

@keyframes spin {
  100% {  transform: rotate(359deg); }
  }
```

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the markup shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add transparent background**

```
$('.loading').css('background', 'transparent');
```

**Remove the loading div**

```
$('.loading').hide();
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHXL8/1/)

Answer (score 28):

I was able to do a loading overlay but only with the addition of an extra container.

```
<div class="loading style-2"><div class="loading-wheel"></div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8k2NV/2/

Answer (score 2):

there is a few ways to create this effect, the easiest would be using 
    .loading{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}
[check this article for other options](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/)